# Graylog How do I include message data in alert email?

Tags: email, graylog

I am having trouble adding relevant information to the alert emails sent from Graylog. I would like to include the actual log message that generated the email alert in the actual email alert. I am attempting to use the *"message"* variables does seem to work. No data is inserted into the email.

Does anyone have examples of how to include *message* information in an email alert?

This is with Graylog 1.2.1

Here are the variables that I am using that do not work:

```
 ${foreach backlog message}${message.source}${end}  
 ======================
 Message Timestamp: ${message.timestamp}
 Message Source: ${message.source}
 Message: ${message.message} 
 Level: ${message.level} 
 Process ID: ${message.process_id} 
 Application: ${message.application_name}
 Facility: ${message.facility}
 ======================
```

These variables that appear in the email template do work:

```
 ====================== 
 Alert Description: ${check_result.resultDescription} 
 Date: ${check_result.triggeredAt}
 Stream ID: ${stream.id}
 Stream title: ${stream.title}
 Stream description: ${stream.description} ${if stream_url}
 Stream URL: ${stream_url}${end}
 ======================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the help of a colleague.

Come to fine out, a "call back" is not required for the email alerting.

Removing the callback still the alert still posts and email.

Within the alert you can set it to include 1 or more of the message in the email alert.